# Where can I put "who knows what else" in a sentence?

Tags: grammar

I want to put the phase "who knows what else" in a sentence. For example:

> I cannot find my key since I've already searched my whole bag. It got lost somewhere.

I want to put "who knows what else" or "what else" or "else" in the last sentence. for example:

> - Who knows what other places it got lost.
> - I lost my key somewhere who knows what else.
> - I lost my key who knows what other places.

Which of those are valid? How can this phrase be used?

Comment: Where  would you put it? Please write it out.

Comment: anywhere possible all ways I want to know

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to say. Do you mean "Who knows what other places I should look?"

Comment: Or do you mean, "Who knows what else might be lost"?

Comment: Who knows what other places it got lost. or I lost my key somewhere who know what else. or I lost my key who know what other places.

Comment: It sounds like you are just trying to give several examples of where you can drop "who knows what else" into a sentence, without really caring about what the sentence might mean. Please let us know if my edited version reflects what you are trying to learn.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find my key since I've already searched my whole bag. It got lost somewhere.

The OP's question: I want to put "who knows what else" or "what else" or "else" in the last sentence.

- Who knows what else I lost when I lost my key?
- What else did I lose when I lost my key?
- Who knows where else I might have lost it, besides in my bag?
- What else did I lose?

Comment: Thank you. If I am not sure that my key is in bag or not, since I tried to find it not throughly yet, I can say "Who knows where else I might have lost it, besides in my bag?"

Comment: Yes, I included that. "since I have not yet searched for it thoroughly".